# RollOver ElasticSearch index with its related Aliases

Tags: elasticsearch, alias, opensearch, elasticsearch-indices

I've managed to Rollover my index, `index_example-0001` using
**"opendistro.index_state_management.rollover_alias": "aliasName"**
however the other related aliases are NOT being rolled with it.

I'm using OpenSearch and for the rollover process I'm using a template file and defined the alias names in it, so the alias field is being created in the new index but all the Filters data in it is lost.

```
"index_example-000004" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "aliasName" : {               //this is used for the rollover process
         "is_write_index" : true
       },
      "anotherAliasName" : { }      // another alias that i want to rollover with the index
    } 
    ...
  }
```

it doesn't make sense that I have to manually take care of it every time there is a rollover process.

Can I rollover an index with it's Aliases? Can it be done?

Comment: share also the policy and the index-template

Comment: Hi, it was a known bug in OpenSearch. not sure if it was fixed in the latest version. Toda..

Comment: Bevakasha :) tried to help :) BTW, the subject should be "Opensearch" rather than "Elastic..." am I wrong? (I was struggling with rollover issues lately)